# Swapping nodes in linked lists on classes

Tags: c++, sorting, nodes, swap, singly-linked-list

my problem is that after running program the only thng I get after swapping is head element and 3rd element of a list, no matter which elements I am swapping.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
class List;

class element{
        private:
                int number;
                element* next;
                friend class List;
                friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &,const List &);

        public:
                element(int data){
                        number=data;
                }

                int getData(){
                        return number;
                }

};

class List{
        private:
                element* head;
                int size;
                friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &,const List &);
        public:
                List(){
                        head=NULL;
                        size=0;
                }

                List(const List &lista){
                        //cout << "wyw" << endl;
                        //fflush(stdout);
                        if (lista.size==0){
                                size=0;
                                head=NULL;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                size=0;
                                head=NULL;
                                element* tmp=lista.head;
                                while(tmp!=NULL){
                                        cout << tmp->number << " ";
                                        fflush(stdout);
                                        this->addToList(tmp->number);
                                        tmp=tmp->next;
                                }
                        }

                }

                ~List(){
                        if (head!=NULL){
                                element* tmp=head;
                                element *temp;
                                while(tmp!=NULL){
                                        temp=tmp->next;
                                        delete tmp;
                                        tmp=temp;
                                }
                                head=NULL;
                        }
                }

                void addToList(int data){
        //              cout << "Ja sie wywolalem" << endl;

                        element* newNode=new element(data);
                        newNode->next=NULL;
                        element *tmp=head;
                        if (tmp!=NULL){
                                while(tmp->next!=NULL){
                                        tmp=tmp->next;
                                }
                                tmp->next=newNode;
                        }
                        else{
                                head=newNode;
                        }
                        size++;

                }

                int popSelected(element *deleted){
                        int value=deleted->number;
                        element* tmp;
                        if (head==deleted){
                                 delete head;
                                 head=NULL;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                tmp=head;
                                while(tmp->next!=deleted)
                                        tmp=tmp->next;
                                tmp->next=deleted->next;
                                delete deleted;
                                size--;
                        }

                        return value;
                }



                element* getPrevious(element* lol){
                    element* tmp;
                    if (lol==head)
                        return NULL;
                    else{
                        tmp=head;
                        while(tmp->next!=lol)
                            tmp=tmp->next;
                        return tmp;
                    }

                }


                void Swap(element** before, element **ahead){
                    if (head==NULL || (*before)==NULL || (*ahead)==NULL){
                        cout << "Nothing to swap";
                        return;
                    }

                    element* prev=getPrevious(*before);
                    element* prev2=getPrevious(*ahead);
                    element* tmp=(*before)->next;
                    if(prev!=NULL)
                        prev->next=(*ahead);
                    if (prev2!=NULL)
                        prev2->next=(*before);
                    (*before)->next=(*ahead)->next;
                    (*ahead)->next=tmp;
                    if (head==(*before))
                        head=(*ahead);
                    else{
                        if (head==(*ahead))
                            head=(*before);

                    }
                }

                void SortTest(){
                    Swap(&(head->next->next), &(head));
                }



                List& operator=(const List& lista){
                        if (&lista==this) return *this;
                        if (this->head!=NULL){
                                element* tmp=head;
                                element *temp;
                                while(tmp!=NULL){
                                        temp=tmp->next;
                                        delete tmp;
                                        tmp=temp;
                                }
                                head=NULL;
                        }
                        if (lista.size==0){
                                size=0;
                                head=NULL;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                size=0;
                                head=NULL;
                                element* tmp=lista.head;
                                while(tmp!=NULL){
                                       this->addToList(tmp->number);
                                        tmp=tmp->next;
                                }
                        }

                        return *this;
                }

                List  operator+(const List &lista){
                        List newList;
                        element *tmp=this->head;
                        while (tmp!=NULL){
                                newList.addToList(tmp->number);
                                tmp=tmp->next;
                        }
                        tmp=lista.head;
                        while (tmp!=NULL){
                                newList.addToList(tmp->number);
                                tmp=tmp->next;
                        }
                        return newList;
                }

                bool operator==(const List &lista){
                        if (this->size==lista.size)
                                return true;
                        else
                                return false;
                }

                bool operator>(const List &lista){
                        if (this->size>lista.size)
                                 return true;
                        else
                                return false;
                }

                bool operator<(const List &lista){
                        if (this->size<lista.size)
                                return true;
                        else
                                return false;
                }
};


istream & operator>>(istream &str, List &lists){
        int data;
        str >> data;
        lists.addToList(data);
        return str;
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream &str,const List &lists){
        element*tmp=lists.head;
        if (tmp==NULL){
                str << "List is empty" << endl;
        }
        else{
                while(tmp!=NULL){
                        str <<"(" <<  tmp->number << ")" << "--";
                        tmp=tmp->next;
                }
        str << "NULL" << endl << "Size of list: " << lists.size << endl;
        }
        return str;
}


int main(){
        List lista;
        cin >> lista;
        cin >> lista;
        List list2=lista;
        cout << "Lista nr 1" << endl << lista;
        cout << "Lista nr 2" << endl << list2;
        cin >> list2;
        cout << "Lista nr 2 po zmianie danych" << endl << list2;
        cin >> list2;
        cin >> list2;
        cout << list2 << endl << endl << "Tests!" << endl;
        list2.SortTest();
        cout << list2 << endl;
        //cout << list2;
        return 0;
}
```

Please don't judge me for this code, I'm totally newbie in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some handling of the case where the elements you want to swap is just after each other.

Look at A->B->C and swap(B, C)

```
                element* prev=getPrevious(*before); // prev point to A
                element* prev2=getPrevious(*ahead); // prev2 point to B
                element* tmp=(*before)->next;       // tmp point to C
                if(prev!=NULL)
                    prev->next=(*ahead);            // A->C
                if (prev2!=NULL)
                    prev2->next=(*before);          // B->B
                (*before)->next=(*ahead)->next;     // B->NULL
                (*ahead)->next=tmp;                 // C->C
```

So the result is A->C->C-> .... and B is lost.

EDIT:
After comment from OP

You have to identify the special cases one by one. Let us call the elements to swap for A and B.

Normal case (where A and B are safe away from each other and not at the start):

```
prevA = "Element before A"
nextA = A->next
prevB = "Element before B"
nextB = B->next

Swap:
  prevA->next = B
  B->next = nextA
  prevB->next = A
  A->next = nextB
```

Now you'll have to consider the special cases (and handle them first).

Case 1 : A == B
Just return

Case 2 : prevA == NULL

In this case you need to

```
head = B
```

instead of

```
prevA->next = B
```

Case 3 : prevB == NULL

Similar to case 2

Case 4 : nextA == B

```
prevA->next = B
B->next = A
A->next = nextB
```

case 5 : nextA == B and prevA == NULL

```
head = B
B->next = A
A->next = nextB
```

Case 6: ....

and so on.

Continue to identify all the special cases and you'll end up with code that works.

I could provide the code for you but I guess you'll learn more by working through it yourself.

Comment: Ok, but new problem is when I'm trying to do it with nodes which are not adjacent I lost list. FOr example when I have list {5,1,36,4,9,65} and i want to swap head(which is 5) and head->next->next->next(which is 4), after swapping i get {5,9,65} and nothing more. I lost everything from next of one node to second node.

Answer (score 0):

In your Swap method I made two changes.  First is I made the arguments just a pointer instead of a double pointer.  This is because you can lose track on an element if you are not careful.  The second is I moved the 'tmp' variable a few lines lower because the lines that swap the previous node's next could make before->next different.
So Swap is now:

```
void Swap(element* before, element *ahead){
   if (head == NULL || before == NULL || ahead == NULL){
      cout << "Nothing to swap";
      return;
   }

   element* prev = getPrevious(before);
   element* prev2 = getPrevious(ahead);

   if (prev != NULL)
      prev->next = ahead;
   if (prev2 != NULL)
      prev2->next = before;
   element* tmp = before->next;
   before->next = ahead->next;
   ahead->next = tmp;
   if (head == before)
      head = ahead;
   else{
      if (head == ahead)
         head = before;

   }
}
```

And so your SortTest would be:

```
void SortTest(){
   Swap(head->next->next, head);
}
```

For your main function to test this I used:

```
int main(){
   List l;
   l.addToList(1);
   l.addToList(2);
   l.addToList(3);
   l.SortTest();
   cout << l << endl;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Have you tested this? Example: `H->A->B->C` and swap(A, B). So before=A, ahead=B, prev=H, Prev2=A. Now you do 1) H->B and 2) A->A and 3) tmp=B and 4) A->C and 5) B->B. Look at the result: H->B->B->B->.... It seems A and C has been lost

Comment: @nielsen Yes.  A->B->C and swap(A,B).  So before=A, ahead=B, prev=NULL, Prev2=A.  Now you do 1) A->A and 2) tmp=A and 3) A->C and 4) B->A and 5) Head=B so H->B->A->C->NULL.  You can try this with SortTest as Swap(head, head->next); with the main function I posted.

Comment: Correct - I meshed up. Due to step 2) A->A step 3 will be tmp=A instead of tmp=B as I thought. Consequently step 5 will B->A instead of B->B as I thought. So in the end: H->B->A->C. You are correct.